# Как узнать на какой именно записи случилась ошибка при обработке запроса?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Дано: есть большая табличка CuteTable, в ней поле MegaField типа varchar(20), в этом поле хранятся даты определенного формата.
При попытке сделать select convert(DATETIME,MegaField,121) from CuteTable случается облом и вываливается ошибка конвертации. Я хочу узнать какая запись тлетворно влияет на табличку, и выкорчевать ее с корнем. Как это правильно сделать?
Доступен инструментарий ms sql management studio 2012.
Субд соответственно mssql 2012

Comment: Какую СУБД вы используете?

Comment: @Free_ze: mssql

Comment: в oracle, я бы эту задачу решал сторед процедурой:  

1) сделал бы временную таблицу (структура - копия оригинальной + еще одно поле чтоб хранить тип данных который получается при вызове функции convert от MegaField)  
2) открыл бы курсор на `select *` из оригинальной и записывал бы по 1му все во "временную" таблицу, ошибки в игнор.  
3) разница содержимого 2х таблиц - все невалидные записи.

однако применим ли такой подход к mssql я не в курсе :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод деления попалам. У большинства баз данных для select есть limit и offset. Вначале делаете запрос для первой половины данных (только не забудьте отсортировать, иначе будете долго искать). Если в первой половине нет, тогда оно гарантированно в второй половине.

При таком подходе, даже есть у Вас 10.000.000 записей, то Вам нужно не более 24 запросов.

Если же Ваша версия БД не поддерживает limit\offset, то можно просто использовать id для этой цели, даже если там есть разрывы.

Comment: В конце концов именно так и сделал. 
Вот костыль для лимит-оффсет на mssql если кто-то будет искать

SELECT col1, col2 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow

Comment: Думаю, будет хорошо, опубликовать значения полей, которые мешали выполнению запроса. Подозревают, что это был null или просто текст.

Comment: Нет, это был не null, null окей отрабатывает. 
В нескольких случаях это была дата в формате старых IE, с буквой T, 
в одном случае - дата меньше минимального DateTime в mssql

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
select * from CuteTable  where isdate(MegaField)=0
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую)  
Мне конечно значительно интереснее более общее решение задачи. Ситуация "применить запрос ко всем записям в таблице и выбрать те записи на которых он обломался" интуитивно кажется мне настолько стандартной, что для нее наверняка существует какое-нибудь шаблонное решение. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Я вам стандартное решение и предложил, в смысле использования встроенных функция для этого и предназначенных. Есть ещё, например, isnumeric...